# How to sort by label name in Grafana

Tags: grafana, promql

I use `rate(nginx_server_bytes{job="$job", host!~'localhost'}[5m]) > 0` for build, it lists all virtual hosts and shows incoming and outgoing traffic.
Information is displayed first all outgoing then all incoming

How do I sort by host?

Now:

```
{direction="in", host="*", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="in", host="example1.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="in", host="example2.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="*", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="example1.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="example2.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
```

I need:

```
{direction="in", host="example1.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="example1.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="in", host="example2.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="example2.com", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="in", host="*", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
{direction="out", host="*", instance="sat0:9913", job="sat0", job_n="nginx"}
```